# regex on javascript, what it does?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex in my code:

```
const date = new Date();
const result = date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, '$1$3');
console.log(result);
//"8:58 AM"
```

In some cases (an android emulator) it shows "08:58". I'm not good on regex:

```
replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, '$1$3')
```

what it means that replace?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex removes the second group aka `(:[\d]{2})` which in your new date exemple is the seconds of the time
`new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` outputs 15:09:22 (at the time of writing)

note that

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, '$1')
```

is enough to write hh:mm,

EDIT : the `$3` is specialy usefull for 12-based hour system (AP/PM) as it print the rest of the string (aka PM or AM), you are calling `toLocaleTimeString()` that why it is local and dependant of the system

There exist other solution to write hh:mm
eg

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(`${(''+date.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')}:${(''+date.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')}`);
```

Comment: Very nice. The last console.log shows time as `9:8` though. Very informative answer btw.

Comment: Thanks ive edited by casting the number to string, then calling padstart to add zeroes if needed (its the afternoon her ei forgot to think :) )

Answer (score 2):

This regex removes two specific number in the given string.

**Example** :

```js
const test = '11111:22:33 whatever';

const rep = test.replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, '$1$3');

console.log(rep);
```

---

https://regex101.com/r/TlUuMF/1